# Sql to update column values with values from other columns for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have multiple tables containing columns 'Name' and 'NameEN'.

I need to update column 'NameEN' with values form column 'Name'

I know how to update single tables with

```
Update Table
set NameEN = Name
```

and I know how to get the list of tables containing the column 'NameEN'

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%NameEN%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Can I somehow combine the 2 queries to update all tables that contain the column 'NameEN'?

I'm using mssms and the server is running ms sql server 14.0.1 if that's important.

Comment: This would generally require dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command EXECUTE sp_executesql:
You can find example on link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
You can build a sql statement by the system table query to find the tables you need to update and then feed the results to the sp_executesql function. You can either use a cursor to loop through the results or just copy the resulting statements into code editor and run it manually.